# button submit trigger on enter

Tags: html, forms, xhtml, triggers, dhtml

This is probally small question for a pro.

i want to know if i replace input submit button with button (type=submit), would it still be trigger on enter (keyboard) and if yes, then which browser wont trigger it?

```
<button type="submit"><span>i was replaced from input button</span></button>
 span was added just for css fancy button style
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be triggered in all standard compliant browsers, since [`type="submit"` creates a submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5):

> Buttons created with the BUTTON
>   element function just like buttons
>   created with the INPUT element, but
>   they offer richer rendering
>   possibilities:

Answer (score 1):

same thing, the `button` allows you to put content, like text or images